# Change Django slug for an existing object?

Tags: django, postgresql

How does one change the slug for an existing object?  I have two objects with conflicting slugs and I need to change one to fix the problem.  Is there a way to do this in the admin interface?  I'm not seeing one.

Comment: How is the slug computed?  Can you show at least the relevant part of your model?

Comment: I don't understand, what is preventing you from changing it? Can you post some code you have tried? If this is a one-time thing you could just change it in the admin.

Comment: @aganders3 clarified the question.  Can you detail how to do this in the admin interface as an answer?

Comment: Well, for example, I have a model `Album` in my app `gallery` with a `SlugField` and it shows up [like so](http://imgur.com/EaWv5) in the admin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that a) The appropriate app is registered to appear in the admin interface, and b), the `slug` is set to be included. In `admin.py` of the relevant app, you need to make sure that `slug` is in the `fields` attribute:

**admin.py**

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = ( ... , 'slug', ... )
admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

furthremore, you should try to avoid getting into a situation where two records have the same slug. You can do this by adding `unique=True` to the model field.

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
```

If there are problems with the above, you will have to manually change one of the slugs in the DB or use the shell:

```
> manage.py shell
> from myapp.models import MyModel
> obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=0) # or whatever the id is for the problematic obj
> obj.slug = "new-slug"
> obj.save()
```

Comment: Not able to check this out yet, but it looks right and I don't want to wait too long before accepting an answer.